# How to resolve Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, next.js, postman

when I am testing the API in the POSTMAN I get Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client error in the vs code terminal.

```
error - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
    at ServerResponse._res.setHeader (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:129:24)
    at sendJson (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:195:9)
    at ServerResponse.apiRes.json (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:351:31)
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/users/index.js:55:21)
    at Object.apiResolver (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:363:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async DevServer.runApi (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:487:9)
    at async Object.fn (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:749:37)
    at async Router.execute (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:253:36)
    at async DevServer.run (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:384:29)
    at async DevServer.run (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:741:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\Tutorials\CRUD_mongoDB\crud-app-mongodb\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:322:20) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT',
  page: '/api/users'
```

This is the api/users/index.js page code :

```js
import connectMongo from "../../../database/conn";
import { getUser } from "../../../database/controller";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  connectMongo().catch(() =>
    res.status(405).json({ error: "Eoor in the connection" })
  );

  //type of req
  //GET , POST , PUT , DELETE

  const { method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      getUser(req, res);
      res.status(200).json({ method, name: "GET Req" });
      break;
    case "POST":
      res.status(200).json({ method, name: "POST Req" });
      break;
    case "PUT":
      res.status(200).json({ method, name: "PUT Req" });
      break;
    case "DELETE":
      res.status(200).json({ method, name: "DELETE Req" });
      break;
    default:
      res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]);
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
      break;
  }

  res.status(200).json({ name: "John Doe" });
}
```

When I send GET request to API I got the above error,  I want to get a empty array because my db is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the switch cases will be called and it will execute `res.status()`, and after the switch you again have `res.status()`, and it will error out because the previos `res.status()` is already called.

The solution is to add `return` statement before each `res.status()`:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  await connectMongo();

  //type of req
  //GET , POST , PUT , DELETE

  const { method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      getUser(req, res);
      return res.status(200).json({ method, name: "GET Req" });
      break;
    case "POST":
      return res.status(200).json({ method, name: "POST Req" });
      break;
    case "PUT":
      return res.status(200).json({ method, name: "PUT Req" });
      break;
    case "DELETE":
      return res.status(200).json({ method, name: "DELETE Req" });
      break;
    default:
      res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]);
      return res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
      break;
  }

  return res.status(200).json({ name: "John Doe" });
}
```

Comment: I am stilling getting the error.

Comment: Oh wait, are your `connectMongo` returns the Promise? If yes, you should await for `connectMongo` Promise as well. Just add `await` before it. I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: The last return will never be called since the switch case will cover all possible code paths